# .ES Domains and WHOIS information

Tags: domains, web-hosting

I am interested in registering a `.es` domain - but what will show up on a WHOIS?

`thelettervsixtim.es` for example seems to only list the name and email. Same with `itun.es`, and others like `broni.es`, etc. It seems like they offer no real privacy stuff for this extension - yet that's all I see for those domains, is this typical?

What can I actually expect to be listed? I'm fine with just a name / email being listed, but I don't know if this is some kind of special case for these domains that I'm somehow unaware of where they only have minimal information listed? I'm obviously entering plenty during the registration like phone number and address but I can't seem to find anything for certain on whether this will end up be listed on the WHOIS for it or not.

Comment: I fully understand these days the importance of privacy and can certainly empathize with your concerns. I registered for a privacy service because of the snail mails, e-mails, phone calls, etc.